# Android NFCA issues

Tags: android, nfc

I have writted some data to NFC tag sucessfully.
Now I would like to read all the blocks for double check.
My codes looks like this and got TAG was lost exception:

```
byte[] UIDFrame = new byte[] { (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00 };
try {
    NfcA nfcvTag = NfcA.get(myTag);
    nfcvTag.close();
    nfcvTag.connect();
    response = nfcvTag.transceive(UIDFrame);
    ...
}
```

Someone said IsoDep can fix this issue, but if I rewrote the code to

```
IsoDep aaa = IsoDep.get(myTag);
```

then I found aaa is null.

Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks so much

Comment: What type of tag do you use? (Or show us how you write to the tag, so that we can see what command-set you use, as this might indicate what tag type you use...)

Comment: byte[] mydata = new byte[] 
{(byte) 0x91,0x02,0x0a,0x48,0x73,0x12,(byte) 0xd1,0x02,...}
Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(mydata);

if (writeTag(message, detectedTag)) 
{
......
}

Comment: So what does `writeTag` do?